# Passing element Id to function run by forEach on array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a classic JavaScript function that takes an object, creates an element with object values and attaches it DOM:

```
//the object
const myObj= {
  id: 1,
  name: "Mike",
};
//getElementBy
const gId = function (id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};
//the function
function createProfileElementDOM(obj, parentId) { //provide object and element id for appending 
  const demo = gId(parentId);
  const newEl = document.createElement("div");
  newEl.className = "user-profile";
  newEl.innerHTML = `${obj.id} <spam> ${obj.name} <span>`;
  demo.appendChild(newEl);
}

createProfileElementDOM(myObj, "demo")
```

And it works ok for this simple scenario.

How to get this to work with forEach on array of objects (JSON):

```
const myObjs= [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Mike",
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Mary",
}
];

myObjs.forEach(createProfileElementDOM(myObj, "demo"))
```

This doesn't work, while it does work if I didn't have custom parameters in createProfileElementDOM function ie `myObjs.forEach(createProfileElementDOM)`

Do I need separate function to make it work? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myObjs.forEach(createProfileElementDOM(myObj, "demo"))` :  This means you're passing the execution result of `createProfileElementDOM(myObj, "demo")` to first parameter of `forEach` which expects a function but ends up getting `undefined` in your case. So yeah you can use a wrapper function like so :-

`myObjs.forEach((myObj) => createProfileElementDOM(myObj, "demo"))`

One more approach could be the following (this is known as `currying` - basically we are dividing the function with n parameters into n nested functions with single parameter) :-

```
function createProfileDOMElement(parentId) { //provide parentID of the object for appending

// return a new function which remembers that parentId and now can work with any obj passed to it.
 return function(obj)
{
  const demo = gId(parentId);
  const newEl = document.createElement("div");
  newEl.className = "user-profile";
  newEl.innerHTML = `${obj.id} <spam> ${obj.name} <span>`;
  demo.appendChild(newEl);
}
}
```

`let createProfileDOMElementWithParentId = createProfileDOMElement(parentId);`

and use it like :-

`myObjs.forEach(createProfileDOMElementWithParentId)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct syntax for the `forEach()` function for it to work.

```
myObjs.forEach(function (myObj) {
    createProfileElementDOM(myObj, 'demo')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another syntax variant that is more common in modern JS:

```
myObjs.forEach((myObj) => {
    createProfileElementDOM(myObj, 'demo')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Signature of forEach is `forEach(callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])`. So you need to access the `id` from the callback function itself instead of passing it through the `forEach`

```js
const gId = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};
//the function
function createProfileElementDOM(obj, parentId) {
  const demo = gId('demo');
  const newEl = document.createElement("div");
  newEl.className = "user-profile";
  newEl.innerHTML = `${obj.id} <spam> ${obj.name} <span>`;
  demo.appendChild(newEl);
}

const myObjs = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Mike",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary",
  }
];

myObjs.forEach(createProfileElementDOM)
```

```css
.user-profile {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: I know ```myObjs.forEach(createProfileElementDOM)```... but the idea is to generalize the function by providing id as argument... for later use, or dynamic scenario